# WordPress WooCommerce Membership plan add column to list

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, add-filter, woocommerce-memberships

I found this 2 filters for WooCommerce to extend the membership plan list:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-wc_user_membership_columns', array( $this, 'customize_columns' ) );
add_filter( 'manage_edit-wc_user_membership_sortable_columns', array( $this, 'customize_sortable_columns' ) );
```

I want to add a new column with the memberships plan id to show.
any suggestion on how to use that in the functions.php

Answer (score 0):

You found the correct filter `manage_edit-wc_user_membership_columns` – it allows to add a column in membership plans, example:

```
add_filter( 'manage_edit-wc_user_membership_columns', 'my_add' );
function my_add( $columns ) {

    $columns['id_of_the_plan'] = 'Memberships plan id';

    return $columns;

}
```

Once you insert this code in your current theme `functions.php` file or in a custom plugin, the column will appear. Now it is time to add the data to it. `manage_posts_custom_column` will help with it.

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column', 'my_id' );
function my_id( $column ) {
    if( $column == 'id_of_the_plan' ) {
        $m = wc_memberships_get_user_membership( get_the_ID() );
        echo $m->plan_id;
    }
}
```

The original code is taken from [this example](https://rudrastyh.com/woocommerce/columns.html#membership_plan_ID_column).